# How to remove zeros from a 1D tensor - TensorFlow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Given a 1D tensor (just to be clear, not array): `[0,2,0,1,-3]`, I'd like to get back just the values different than zero. Following the example, I'd like to get back `[2,1,-3]` as the result. How can I do that in TensorFlow.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First we need to find the indexes of the non-zeros values by using `tf.whereAsync` on the tensor casted to `bool`. That way all values except 0 values are `true` and their indexes are thus collected.
- With `tf.gather` we create a new tensor by collecting the values at the previous indexes.

```js
t = tf.tensor1d([0,2,0,1,-3])
indices = await tf.whereAsync(t.cast('bool'))
tf.gather(t, indices.reshape([-1])).print()
```

Comment: Such a clever solution